# How to exclude WEB-INF/libs from being deployed in wildfly

Tags: java, ejb, war, wildfly, web-inf

I am installing a war file in a Wildfly.

The package contains EJB and WS.

The dependencies are located in `myWar.war/WEB-INF/lib`.

My EJBs (annotated with `@Stateless`) located in `myWar.war/WEB-INF/classes` are correctly scanned by wildfly and deployed.

The problem is that some dependencies are also annotated with `@Stateless`, and Wildfly also deploy them.

I have no direct control over the dependencies I need to import.

Is there any way to exclude myWar.war/WEB-INF/lib from being scanned by 
`org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor` and deployed ?

Comment: Take a look at [WildFly's Class Loading Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly). Perhaps you could make use of *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: Cant you just exclude the jars in lib/ during packaging?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. Neither of these solutions works. I don't think it is possible. If I find a way I'll post it here.